# How to filter by date with Field using Blazor DxDataGridColumn DevExpress?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, devexpress

I'm trying make function the searching when the user fill the Field of date in DxDataGridColumn, as image below:

[image]

But the searching don't function.

In razor.cs I maked this:

```
private ValueDTO valueDTO;

private string importDateValue => this.valueDTO.ImportDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

And in the razor file I uused the code below:

```
<DxDataGridColumn Caption="@Localizer\["Data de Importação"\]"
                  Field="importDateValue"
                  Width="170px"\>
                  <DisplayTemplate\>
                          @{
                              var item = context as ValueSummaryDTO;
                              if (item?.ImportDate != null && item?.ImportDate.Value != DateTimeOffset.MinValue)
                           {
                              <span\>@item.ImportDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")\</span\>
                           }
                           }
                  </DisplayTemplate\>
</DxDataGridColumn\>
```

But the result of search don't right function. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to have a property inside your SummaryDTO with the date already converted to string. Then, you can bind the DxDataGridColumn to this property. It should behave as any other text field.